# MVC 4 Azure Active Directory Groups Authorize tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

We are migrating a series of legacy .NET 4.7 MVC applications to from Active Directory Authenticaion to Azure Active Directory.

We have sucessfully got azure sign in working

Most applications. are using [Authorize=("Role=XXX")] However the role claims are no longer working.

We have enabled the API Permission "Directory.Read.All" on the application in the azure portal / changed the    "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Are you still looking for any help on this